# NPOI - Writing to file corrupts .xlsx workbook

Tags: c#, xlsx, npoi

I have a piece of code that is currently writes to a `.xls` workbook (`HSSFWorkbook`) with no issue.  However when I try to use the same code to write to a `.xlsx` workbook (`XSSFWorkbook`) the archive becomes corrupted and cannot be opened in excel.

The following code is what I am using to access the workbook, edit the workbook, and then save back to the workbook.  I originally assumed that the code that I was using to edit the workbook was the issue, but after commenting it out the issue still persists.

```
IWorkbook workbook;
using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(fileName).Contains("xlsx"))
    {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    }
    else
    {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    }
}

//Code that edits workbook which is currently commented out

using (var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    workbook.Write(file);
}
```

I have tried running this code against a blank `.xlsx` workbook and the file becomes corrupt, and is no longer able to be opened.

I am using the latest stable version of NPOI from nuget: `NPOI 2.1.3.1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying everything that was mentioned on [NPOI's Codeplex](http://npoi.codeplex.com/workitem/12847) to no avail, I tried messing with the `FileStream` properties and was able to get the blank `.xslx` to save.  I am using the following code to write back to the file:

```
using (var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    workbook.Write(file);
}
```

This has fixed the primary issue of saving a back to a `XssfWorkbook`.

Comment: For future readers: note that saving an empty workbook (right after `new XSSFWorkbook();` also corrupts the `.xlsx` file. To avoid this, create an empty sheet in the workbook (`workbook.CreateSheet()`) before saving the workbook.

Comment: Good find, I was also WTF because `FileMode.Open` is working with `.xls` files but not `.xlsx` files.

Comment: I was getting corrupt files because I wasn't using the Filestream object in a Using block (instead I was calling Close() on it). I'm guessing it didn't flush the file properly.