# NPOI Write Corrupts File - Bare Ampersands

Tags: excel, apache-poi, corrupt, ampersand, npoi

Using NPOI 2.1.3.1, I am trying to read an existing Excel (*.xlsx) workbook, modify it, and then write it back to the original file. After reading various threads (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142337/npoi-writing-to-file-corrupts-xlsx-workbook)), I still cannot find a solution to the problem I'm having.

When I write the file to disk and then try to open it again in Excel, I get the following error:

> We found a problem with some content in (filename. Do you want us to
> try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
> workbook, click Yes.

Clicking "Yes" fixes various problems in the Excel file, after which I see the following report of the fixes performed:

> Replaced Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part with XML error.  Illegal
> name character. Line 3, column 3891168.
>
> Replaced Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet19.xml part with XML error.  Illegal name
> character. Line 1, column 699903.
>
> Removed Records: Formula from /xl/calcChain.xml part (Calculation properties)

I unzipped the *.xlsx file and found the sheets mentioned and discovered that the character it was referring to is a bare ampersand (&) that was not written as "&amp;" in the XML. The original **does** use "&amp;", but the file NPOI wrote does not. I have no idea what the issue is with the formula (third issue).

Here is a complete program that reproduces this issue every single time with the workbook I'm using, with the file name removed:

```
using System.IO;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;

namespace NpoiTest
{
    public sealed class NpoiTest
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XSSFWorkbook workbook;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Path\To\File.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            }

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\Path\To\File.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                workbook.Write(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a test, I wrote pretty much the same program using Apache POI, to see if it was just a universal problem with my workbook, and the result was that POI didn't have any problems.

Here is the complete program:

```
package poitest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class PoiTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Path\\To\\File.xlsx")))
        {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Path\\To\\File.xlsx")))
        {
            workbook.write(out);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is why is NPOI leaving the bare ampersands? Is this just a bug in NPOI?

Comment: Which version of NPOI are you using? And what XML related dependencies have you added to your build?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that. Using NPOI 2.1.3.1. I've updated the question to include that.

Comment: David, so have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Actually, I don't know--since that part of the project never worked properly, we ended up cutting it out months ago.